# Restrict IAM users inside a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-vpc

I have a VPC in which users have access to confidential data and computing resources. For security and intellectual property reasons, this VPC should not allow users to leak information to the outside world (internet).

I need to expose AWS resources on this VPC for users: say allowing users to invoke a lambda function and access an S3 bucket.

To expose the S3 bucket, it was trivial. I created an S3 VPC endpoint and attached on it a policy only granting `s3:*` to the specific bucket. Then I opened access to this specific endpoint in the firewall. If I had granted access to `s3.amazonaws.com` as a whole, users could have created a personal bucket on a foreign AWS account and use it to leak data from within the VPC to their bucket.

Now to expose a specific lambda function, I cannot reuse the same trick, since there is not VPC endpoint for lambda.

How can I expose a specific lambda function in a VPC, without opening access to `lambda.amazonaws.com` as a whole, and thus allowing users to potentially use their own lambdas in a foreign account to leak information from the VPC?

In an ideal world, I would like to be able to restrict all IAM/STS inside this VPC to users of my account. That would prevent anyone from using external AWS credentials from within the VPC to leak information.

--- EDIT

Apparently there is some confusion on what I am trying to prevent here, so let me explain in more details.

Say you are working at company X that has access to very sensitive data. This data should NOT be possible to leak to the outside world (internet).

Company X gives you access to a machine in a VPC that contain these confidential files that you need for some computations. There is a NAT and internet gateway in this VPC, but iptables prevents you from accessing non-white listed address.

Say your computation requires access to an S3 bucket. If access to `s3.amazonaws.com` is freely opened in iptables, then data leak is possible. A malicious employee could create a personal AWS account, and use it from within company X's VPC to upload sensitive data to his personal bucket. This problem can be mitigated by company X by creating an S3 VPC endpoint in the VPC, with a policy only allowing the allowed S3 bucket, and opening iptables only for this VPC endpoint.

My question is: how about AWS lambda?

Since there is no VPC endpoint for AWS lambda, I would need to allow `lambda.amazonaws.com` as a whole in iptables, which basically means that anyone within that VPC can freely use *any* lambda from any AWS account, and thus leak any data they want by uploading it to a personal lambda created in a personal account.

Comment: Can you clarify your setup? How your users invoke lambda? From internet or api gateway? As you pointed out, there are not VPC endpoints for lambda, so the only way to invoke it, is to  use NAT gateway or private API gateway as a proxy if you want to do it from a private subnet.

Comment: > "How your users invoke lambda? From internet or api gateway?"

From internet. I cannot really use an API gateway in front of the lambda, since there are some iam policies attached on the lambda for access control.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Why would using API gateway interfere with IAM policies attached on lambda? There are no VPC endpoint for lambda, thus you can't compare it to S3. But there are VPC endpoints for API gateway.

Comment: > "Why would using API gateway interfere" because the Lambda need to perform access control based on the caller. If the Lambda is called directly, then you can know the IAM user of the caller. If the Lambda is called through an API gateway, then you have no way to know the caller.

Answer (score 1):

AWS does not maintain a relationship between VPCs and users.

Resources are connected to VPCs. Permissions are granted to users. The two concepts do not really intersect.

If you have some particularly sensitive resources that you wish to only provide to certain users, another approach would be to **create another AWS Account** and only create a small subset of users for that account, or only allow a subset of users to assume an IAM Role in that account. This way, there is a direct relationship between "VPCs/Resources" and "Users".

Comment: I don't think you understood the question here. Let me restate the problem: If I give access to AWS lambda to users inside my VPC, then nothing can prevent them from creating a personal AWS account containing a lambda, and call that lambda from within _my_ VPC to leak data. With S3, this is different, because I can create an S3 endpoint inside my VPC which has a policy only allowing access to my bucket. That way users cannot leak data by creating a bucket in their personal account and push data to it.

Comment: If a person creates their own AWS Account, that account does not have access to any resources inside your account. Nobody can run a Lambda function from a different account "in" your VPC. Also, there is no concept of "giving access to AWS Lambda to users inside a VPC". Users do not exist within a VPC, and the Lambda service does not exist inside a VPC. The closest concept is granting IAM permissions for an IAM User to create/invoke a Lambda function.

Comment: It seems my question is still too vague. I added more information to describe the problem. Is it clearer now?

Answer (score -1):

You can add resource based policy to the Lambda and only allow some specific EC2 instances or users to access the function.